# Sequence number and acknowledgement number do not match

Tags: networking, tcp, wireshark

I have been learning wireshark lately. While inspecting TCP segments, I saw a strange situation, at least for me. There was a mismatching SEQ,ACK numbers. Then I realized that difference between two ACK's same as 1 and half package size. However, as far as I know, ACKs are only growing by the full packet size. So what happened here?

```
SEQ        ACK
1          1
2897       8689
5793       13033 <--
8689       14481
11585
14481
```

[image: Image of the trace]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there's not much to go by here, but I'm going to guess that you are capturing packets on the machine sending the large packets, i.e., the packets with 2896 bytes of TCP payload.  As such, you are seeing the packets ***before*** they are IP-fragmented and actually transmitted out on the wire.

But you can't just send 2896 bytes of data onto the wire; Ethernet links typically impose a 1500 byte MTU (Maximum Transmission Unit), and when you account for IP and TCP header overhead, you usually end up with 1460 bytes of available payload or MSS (Maximum Segment Size).  In your case it looks like you're only getting 1448 bytes of available MSS, most likely due to the addition of one or more IP and/or TCP header options.

In any case, the 2896 bytes of payload are going to be fragmented over 2 IP fragments, each containing 1448 bytes of TCP payload.  I'm pretty sure that what you're seeing is an ACK from the receiver after having received 1 full segment plus 1 IP fragment from the next segment.

The previous ACK number was 8689, and 8689 + 2896 = 11585.  Now add 1/2 of the data segment (2896 / 2 = 1448) and you get 11585 + 1448 = 13033.  That's the ACK number you're seeing.  Now add the other 1/2 and you get 13033 + 1448 = 14481, which is the ACK number of the next packet.

I hope that makes sense?

For an in depth look at the drawbacks of local packet captures, I direct you to a well-written blog by Jasper Bongertz titled, ["The drawbacks of local packet captures"](https://blog.packet-foo.com/2014/05/the-drawbacks-of-local-packet-captures/).

Comment: Actually, _fragmentation_ is what happens to IPv4 packets by a router when they are larger than the next MTU. What TCP does is _segmentation_, not fragmentation, breaking the data into segments that fit the IP payload before it gets to IP. This is a real source of confusion for some people.

Comment: Yes, I'm well aware of the difference between fragmentation and segmentation, but there's no getting around that those 2896 byte segments are **not** sent in one IP packet.   I suppose what's much more likely in this case though is that Wireshark's TCP reassembly feature is enabled and there is a Wireshark display filter applied,  such as "tcp", which is causing the first IP fragment not to be displayed, thus adding to the confusion.

Comment: I understand that what you are saying happens, but I wanted to clarify the terminology. We get confused questions about fragmented packets on NE, and spend a lot of time answering about fragmentation, only to find out later that the question is really about segmentation, not fragmentation. I have seen such confused questions on [sf], too. I just thought a comment to clarify the terminology would be appropriate.

Comment: Your point is noted and it has made me realize that fragmentation likely isn't the answer, or at least not the entire answer. If only fragmentation was occurring, then the receiving host's IP stack would have to hold onto the 1st fragment until the 2nd fragment arrived before reassembling them sending it up the stack to the TCP layer. While IP Fragmentation might be occurring, it seems likely that *resegmentation* is almost certainly occurring, and this would explain why the first partial segment is ACK'd.  It would of course be easier to tell if a packet capture at the receiver was available.

Answer (score 1):

Since I do not have reputation to comment the answer of Christopher Maynard, I comment it here.

As Christopher stated correctly the MTU (Maximum Transmission Unit) is standard Ethernet networks is 1500Bytes. However, crafting 1460Bytes (1500Bytes - 20Bytes IP Header - 20Bytes TCP Header, ignoring possible TCP options) TCP segments imposes a high load on the network stack since every segment must be handled separately.

As an example, if I want to transmit 1Mb (equals to 1024*1024Bytes = 1048576Bytes) of data, it would result in 1Mb/1460Bytes = 719 segments. In contrast to 1Mb/65525Bytes (theoretical max TCP segment size) = 16 segments. Since the overhead in the Kernel is mostly independent of the segment/packet size, small segments require much more processing.

To counteract this fact, TCP Segmentation Offloading (TSO) was developed. TSO allows the Kernel to craft TCP segments with maximum size and the NIC (Network Interface Card) uses hardware acceleration to split these segments into the separate TCP segments of 1460Bytes. Therefore, no IP fragmentation is required.